# How can I specify a file without listing the entire file path?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using pandas to read an "output.csv" file by specifying the filepath as :

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\users\user1\desktop\project\output.csv')

While this works perfectly fine on my local machine, is there a way I can code this so anyone who runs the script can use it? I want to be able to hand this script to coworkers who have no knowledge of Python and have them be able to run it without manually changing the username in the path.

I have tried using os.path to no avail:

df = pd.read_csv(os.path.dirname('output.csv'))

SOLUTION: df = pd.read_csv('output.csv'). Simple, embarrassing, and a wonderful building block to learn from. Thank you all.

Comment: If they have no knowledge of Python, why would Python even be installed on their computer?

Comment: @JohnGordon this is kinda stupid question. Software developers develop software that usually runs on someone's computer who does not have any coding knowledge.

Comment: @emranio If this were a standalone executable program, then sure.  But he specifically said "hand this script to coworkers", which strongly suggests he's giving them a `.py` file.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I'm hoping to wrap it nicely as an exe, but I made the assumption that If the script couldn't run for anyone as a .py, simply converting it to a .exe would still carry over the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're shipping out the `output.csv` in the same directory as the python script, you should be able to reference it directly `pd.read_csv('output.csv')`.

If your **need** to get the full path + filename for the file, you should use `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

Finally, if your output.csv is in a static location in all your coworkers computers and you need to get the username, you can use `os.getlogin()` and add it to the path.

So there's a bunch of solutions here depending on your exact problem.

Comment: Thank you. Simple as it may be, I appreciate the help, this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to get an absolute directory path of your application, then contact your csv file to it.

```
import os
abspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(abspath)
csvpath = abspath + '/my_csv_file.csv'
print(csvpath)
```